# Visual studio warning - type conflict

Tags: c#, visual-studio, conflict

This warning make me crazy.

`Warning    CS0436  The type 'TypeName' in TypeAddress conflicts with the imported type 'TypeName' in 'TypeAddress`

TypeNames and TypeAddress are exactly the same.

Why Visual studio warns me about this?

Comment: Right click your `.csproj` file and open it with a text editor. If you Ctrl+F for `TypeName` or `TypeAddress`, how many results do you find? Whatever you're trying to import already exists somewhere. Alternatively, just do a Ctrl+F for `class TypeName` across your entire solution.

Comment: Show us a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example which illustrates your problem so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined something twice within the same namespace, which is not allowed (or to be more precise, one of them gets ignored). E.g. once in your main program, and once in a project or library that it references. You need to remove one of those definitions.

If you can't find it then make sure that your build is up-to-date, by doing Clean Solution or Rebuild Solution.

For more info see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0436

Comment: I can't find it. I clean and rebuild solution before. Actually I got this warning when tried to release my program. I know this is kind of weird.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the project output? Example: Your ConsoleApplication1 project contains a reference to ConsoleApplication1 (.dll)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, what a bad mistake!!! you saved me and I'm not crazy any more. Thanks.